# Split database in magento-2.3.3 at localhost

Tags: magento2

I have tried to split magento databases. I have tried following things.

```
create database magento_quote;
GRANT ALL ON magento_quote.* TO magento_quote@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'magento_quote';
create database magento_sales;
GRANT ALL ON magento_sales.* TO magento_sales@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'magento_sales';
```

When I am running the following command I am getting error like

> Command "setup:db-schema:split-quote" is not defined.

```
php bin/magento setup:db-schema:split-quote --host="127.0.0.1" --dbname="magento_quote" --username="magento_quote" --password="magento_quote
```

Comment: You have made sure you're not trying this on the open source version? It's Magento Commerce (the paid version...) only.

Comment: Thanks for help Yes I am using in open source version.